# Why am I getting this "Out of Bounds" error?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an out of bonds error when I  use this coding to get user input. The user input for `noOfJudges` is how long the array will be. For each judge a score is entered and tested to see if it is between 1 and 10.
Code:

```
  double [] scores = new double [noOfJudges];

  System.out.print("Please enter the next score: ");
  for(scoreEntry = 0; scoreEntry < scores.length; scoreEntry++)
      scores[scoreEntry]=console.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();


      while((scores[scoreEntry] < MIN_SCORE)||(scores[scoreEntry] > MAX_SCORE))
      {
         System.out.print("Please reenter the score (must be between 1.0 and 10.0, in .5 increments): ");
         scores[scoreEntry] = console.nextDouble();
         System.out.println();
      }
```

If anyone wants to be totally great, is there a way to check to see if a number is between 1 and 10 and only in .5 increments?

Comment: From what I can tell, you are getting an OutOfBoundsException because your scoreEntry element has not been reset after your initial for loop . When you call scores[scoreEntry] in your while loop, the value is greater than score.length and goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local variable to the *for loop* or reset `scoreEntry`, because at the end of the *for loop* `scoreEntry` is equal to the length of the array, which is not a valid index...

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop ends,

do a `System.out.println(scoreEntry);`

Therein lies your answer :)

Best,

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You must forgot a pair of `{}`

```
double[] scores = new double[noOfJudges];

System.out.print("Please enter the next score: ");
for(scoreEntry = 0; scoreEntry < scores.length; scoreEntry++) {
    scores[scoreEntry] = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
    while((scores[scoreEntry] < MIN_SCORE) || (scores[scoreEntry] > MAX_SCORE)){
        System.out.print("Please reenter the score " + 
            "(must be between 1.0 and 10.0, in .5 increments): ");
        scores[scoreEntry] = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```